# fluid semi-fluid fluid divs

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

```css
.mid{
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width:10em;
    min-width:5em;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class='mid'>...</div>
```

This code creates one centered div that will expand up to 10em and shrunk to 5em if browser window is small enough. Almost all I want.

Is it possible to create three divs in a row where middle div will behave exactly like .mid (expand up to 10em, shrunk to 5em) with left and right divs behaving like margins on auto: expanding to center .mid and shrinking to 0 if there's not enough space.

The closest solution I have found is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7v1m5g8d/). Only problem is that .mid is not shrinking because td doesn't have mix-width and max-width.

```css
.cont{
    display:table;
   /* table-layout:fixed; /* this prevented shrinking */
    width:100%;
}
.cont div{
    display:table-cell;
    overflow:hidden;

    
}
 .mid{
    width:10em;    /* in table width behaves like max-width*/
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class='cont'>

    <div>left</div>
    <div class='mid'>...</div>
    <div>right</div>
    
</div>
```

Am I missing something or it's not possible to create this layout with in html/css?

Comment: You want all three sections to grow uniformly, the centre starting at `5em` and the others at `0`; until the centre hits `10em` at which point it should remain constant while the sides continue to grow uniformly?

Comment: Yes. As if you would replace `.mid  margins: 0 auto;` with left and right div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the flex properties : http://jsfiddle.net/7v1m5g8d/1/

```css
.cont {
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid blue;
    text-align:center;
}
.cont div {
    flex:1;
}
.cont div.mid {
    /* strippes for demo */
    background:repeating-linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0, transparent 0.9em, gray 0.9em, gray 1em);
    min-width:5em;
    max-width:10em;
    flex:auto;/* reset */
    border:1px solid red;
}
/* do not forget to add prefix-vendor if needed or a script as prefixfree.js :) */
```

```html
<div class='cont'>
    <div>left</div>
    <div class='mid'>...</div>
    <div>right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool. I didn't know that `display:flex` existed and that SO have code shippets till now :)

Comment: @CoR  you can find examples and tutorials here : https://css-tricks.com/search-results/?q=flex :)